# Why does FFMPeg sit at 00:00:00.00 if I start cutting a video a long ways into the file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm cutting audio out of files, and I'm running into an issue. When I run FFMPeg with this command

> FFMPEG.exe -i in.webm -q:a 0 -map a -ss hh:mm:ss -to hh:mm:ss -y out.mp3

If the `-ss` parameter is rather large (lets say `00:30:00`), it takes a long time before it even starts cutting -- It just sits on the below statement for a long time before finally starting.

> size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A

Does anyone know why it would do this and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-ss` after the input name performs a slow seek where ffmpeg decodes all frames but discards till it reaches the seek point.

With `-ss` before `-i`, ffmpeg performs a fast seek.

```
FFMPEG.exe -ss hh:mm:ss -i in.webm -q:a 0 -map a -t hh:mm:ss -y out.mp3
```

But you'll have to specify a duration instead of `to` with most formats.

Comment: I only use FFMPEG every few years, but it always amazes me how much it is the embodiment of the power/complexity trade-off.